# Local MDF file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create an ASP.NET MVC template project and I figured out that the local account data gets stored in a `.MDF` file in `app_data`.

How can I view the data in this database and modify the data directly for testing and validation purposes?

Also any issues with use a local database like this? What happens when I release a new version of my application? Will I be able to import data from the local file to the new local database file?

Comment: `.mdf` file is a **SQL Server** database - so any means to view and/or edit a SQL Server database should work just fine (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio, or the built-in viewer and editors in Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, Click on Menu **`View`** and click on **`Server Explorer`** menu item. A Pop up box either on left or right side, named Server Explorer, will appear. In that under **`Data Connections`** you can find your `database.mdf` file. Expand that `mdf` file, you will find `Tables`. Right click on any `table` and you will get an option `Show Table Data` option which opens a window where you can view your `table` data.

**View -> Server Explorer**

[image: Menu]

**Server Explorer**

[image: Server Explorer]

There is no issue using local database, unless you are just building an application, but once you release your application then you need to put your database to the server along with the publishing files and manage/map a connection string to connect properly. You can use **SQL Server Management Studio** to import or export data from/to your database

Comment: Or better yet - click on the item **SQL Server Object Explorer** (just below the "Server Explorer") - it's basically SQL Server Management Studio **inside of** Visual Studio !

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio,

1. Go To **view** from Menu
2. Search for **Server Explorer** in view..
3. Under the tree **Data Connections** you will find the database you have it as `.mdf` file
4. when your db file is not showing there then you will first connect with server and db file .
5. Checking data by query then right click on db and click on **New Query** a new window will be appear.